# How can I get customer data in a plugin class?

Tags: custom-options, plugin

I'm trying to access logged in customer data in an "after" plugin.

The plugin is working, but I need some logic based on a custom customer attribute.

I try to do this but I get an error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get() on null in /Users/name/file/project/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 170
```

I've tried using create instead of get for the object manager, but I get the same result.

I have a helper function that I use to get this data in some phtml files, but it doesn't seem to work in this class.

Do I have to get this data from somewhere else?

Thanks

```
namespace <company>\EmailCopy\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Container\OrderIdentity;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class SendOrderCopy
{

   private $logger;
   private $objectManager;

   public function __construct(
       LoggerInterface $logger,
       ObjectManager $objectManager

   )
   {
       $this->logger = $logger;
       $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
   }

   public function afterGetEmailCopyTo(OrderIdentity $identity, $emailList)
   {
       $customer = $this->objectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session')->getCustomer();
       $customer = $customer->getData();
       var_dump($customer);
       $emailList[] = "<email>";
       $emailList[] = "<email";
       return $emailList;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point of this was to be able to get a custom attribute every time an email was sent, and CC a local sales rep based on that custom code.

This was the final function to get the customer data

```
  public function afterGetEmailCopyTo(OrderIdentity $identity, $emailList)
    {
        $customerEmail = $identity->getCustomerEmail();
        $customer = $this->_customerRepository->get($customerEmail);
        $territoryCode = $customer->getCustomAttribute('territory_code')->getValue();
        switch ($territoryCode) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```